# How to store a reference of a singleton class?

Tags: c++, singleton

I am working on a project relating to a dealer dealing cards to players.
I have the singleton class `Dealer` and another class called `Player`.

I have made the `instance()` method for `Dealer` and this part is where I am confused:

For the singleton `Player` class, how do I create a private member called `dealer` that holds a reference to the singleton `Dealer` instance?

Comment: Why would you want to have a reference to a singleton class? Every time you need to access the dealer, you do e.g. `Dealer::instance().someMethod()`

Comment: Why would you want a singleton in the first place? You'll regret this decision when you buy more tables and you'll want each to have its own dealer :)

Answer (score 5):

In the first place you should ask yourself, if you **really need a singleton class** to solve this problem at all.

You can always pass the reference to an instance of `Dealer` to the constructor of your `Player` class:

```
class Player {
public:
    Player(Dealer& dealer_) : dealer(dealer_) {}

private:
    Dealer& dealer;
};
```

no matter, wether it was constructed on the stack, on the heap or as singleton instance.

---

> For the singleton `Player` class, how do I create a private member ..._

The [commonly recommended c++ singleton implementation pattern](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf#search=%22meyers%20double%20checked%20locking%22) is

```
class Dealer{
public:
     static Dealer& instance() {
         static Dealer theDealer;
         return theDealer;
     }

     void foo() {}
private:
     Dealer() {}
     Dealer(const Dealer&) = delete;
     Dealer& operator=(const Dealer&) = delete;
};
```

**NOTE:** You don't necessarily need to store a reference to `Dealer` class in your client class, but you can simply access the singleton instance and call the desired non static  member function

```
Dealer::instance.foo();
```

If you insist to create a reference member to the singleton though, you can do:

```
class Player {
public:
    Player() : dealer(Dealer::instance()) {}

private:
    Dealer& dealer;
};
```

Comment: I think the *more* common recommendation is to avoid Singleton altogether, but +1 for the canonical example. I wonder if this can be turned into a template class?

Comment: @MarkRansom Surely, aggreed! But _if_ you need one (for whatever reason), you must fairly agree _this is the commonly recommended way_, don't you? (And of course this can be tuned into templates, I think Scott Meyers invented this pattern and proposed a template solution for it)

Comment: @MarkRansom Found the paper: http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf#search=%22meyers%20double%20checked%20locking%22

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Where in that paper does it suggest this pattern? Mostly he is discussing the potential pitfalls of DCLP. Right at the end he does very briefly mention that a solution can be to initialize prior to main, which would be in line with this solution, but doesn't specifically lay it out, so I would be inclined to believe Meyers Singleton probably has a different original paper.