# Return const reference to singleton

Tags: c++, reference, singleton

I am trying to implement a Singleton pattern with some pre-defined method declarations. I thoght it works but getting a second instance produces another instance.

I cannot change the method declarations or the member variables. I have build a little example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Singleton
{
  private:
    Singleton() {};

    vector<string> data;
    static Singleton *instance;

  public:
    static const Singleton &getInstance()
    {
      if(0 == instance) {
        instance = new Singleton;
      }
      return *instance;
    }

    void push(string &new_element)
    {
      data.push_back(new_element);
    }

    void print()
    {
      for(vector<string>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << endl;
      }
    }
};

Singleton *Singleton::instance = 0;

int main()
{
  Singleton a = Singleton::getInstance();
  Singleton b = Singleton::getInstance();

  string c1 = "Hello";
  string c2 = "World";

  a.push(c1);
  b.push(c2);

  a.print(); // prints only "hello"
}
```

My second attempt was to change a and b to a reference like this:

```
  Singleton &a = Singleton::getInstance();
  Singleton &b = Singleton::getInstance();
```

But this leads to another error:

```
singleton.cpp:40:45: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Singleton&’ from expression of type ‘const Singleton’
singleton.cpp:41:45: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Singleton&’ from expression of type ‘const Singleton’
```

Why does this happen? Can somebody explain, why new instances of Singleton are created?

I did search the web for answers, but nobody really used the Singleton pattern like I have to. (I'd change the inner structure if I could, but this is some kind of homework with given code.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store a reference of a singleton class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549704/how-to-store-a-reference-of-a-singleton-class)

Comment: Why is it returning a `const` reference in the first place? There are no non-const member functions, so you can't do anything with it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour As I said: This code was given to me with the restriction not to change it. I know, it sucks. That's why I'm asking here. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code causes the Singleton instance to be copied:

```
Singleton a = Singleton::getInstance();
```

Changing the code to

```
const Singleton& a = Singleton::getInstance();
```

will fix the problem. You should make the copy constructor (and assignment operator) of Singleton private to disallow copying and assignment at compile time:

```
private:
    Singleton(const Singleton&);
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&);
```

Comment: Changing `getInstance` to return a non-const reference seems more sensible to me. Otherwise, you can't do anything with it.

Comment: Thanks. I did this before, but I cannot change it's contents anymore. So, this pre-declaration is broken by design? I mean, I *need* to change it's values, but given the restriction I won't be able except for const_casting... Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If the singleton needs to be mutable (you need to change its contents), make getInstance return a non-const reference.

Comment: Note: in C++11 use `= delete` after the method declarations to specify they are not to be used.

Answer (score 0):

They need to be `const` references:

```
   const Singleton &a = Singleton::getInstance();
```