# Static local variable gets reinitialized

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, singleton

I have a virtual singleton that i want to implement the `getInstance()` static function for, however each time it is called, the static object gets re-initialised, so i get a new instance each time, any help will be appreciated - this has me very confused.

The class I want to implement the method in:

```
class Pc : public Machine
{
  private:
    ... members ...

  public:
    static Pc* getInstance();

    Pc() {};
    virtual ~Pc() {}

    ... other functions ...
};
```

The parent class:

```
class Machine
{
  public:
    static Machine* getInstance();

    Machine() { }
    Machine(const Machine&) = delete;
    virtual ~Machine() { }

    ... methods ...

    void operator=(const Machine&) = delete;
};
```

Bridge from Machine -> Pc singleton

```
Machine* Machine::getInstance()
{
    return Pc::getInstance();
}
```

I have two sets of code for PC, one which i belive should work, and my current workaround code...

Non working code:

```
Pc* Pc::getInstance()
{
    static Pc* pc = new Pc();
    return pc;
}
```

Working (but bodged) `getInstance()` code:

```
static Pc* pc = nullptr;
Pc* Pc::getInstance()
{
    if(pc == nullptr) {
        pc = new Pc();
    }
    return pc;
}
```

While both compile successfully, after break pointing my code i can see that my expected code returns the same pointer, however after manipulating the object the second call returns a new object, leading me to believe the static variable as been initialized again.

Compiled with the flags:

```
-ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -std=gnu++11 -lgcc
```

(this is for an OS project)

Comment: I'm not sure if this will have any bearing on your issue, but singleton constructors should be declared `private`

Comment: Isn't the second way (the working way) the way a singleton instance is supposed to be created? The not working way creates a new `Pc` everytime it is called.

Comment: @bstar55 Yes they should, I was trying everything to get this working though, and that was left over from fiddling with the code - sadly either way the code doesnt work.

Comment: @gta0004 The static variable SHOULD do exactly the same - preserving its value between calls.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29b5b7758d7ae9d5) @gta0004 No it doesn't. Function local statics are initialized once ... the very first time control flows over the initialization.

Comment: @gta0004, The static variable inside a function is a very common method for wrapping as well.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549704/how-to-store-a-reference-of-a-singleton-class/23549834#23549834

Comment: Tried your code (excluding the `=delete`); same pointer is returned every time.

Comment: @barakmanos The same pointer is returned, however the constructor for Pc gets called again on the second call (and breakpointing the constructor shows that the variables are initialised as before - so its another call to an object that has already been constructed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok! After 3 days of head scratching i have found the cause of the error! GCC expects you to supply a few functions for yourself if you use `--ffreestanding` to compile your code, incase anyone else has this (granted very obscure) error, i have put the code i used below (a huge thanks to [osdev.org](http://osdev.org/) for this code!!)

```
__extension__ typedef int __guard __attribute__((mode(__DI__)));

extern "C" int __cxa_guard_acquire(__guard* g)
{
    return !*(char*)(g);
}

extern "C" void __cxa_guard_release(__guard* g)
{
    *(char *)g = 1;
}

extern "C" void __cxa_guard_abort (__guard*)
{
}
```

Comment: These are only safe for single-threaded code!  GCC/clang depend on these to provide mutual exclusion if a 2nd thread wants to read the static local while another thread has started but not finished initializing it.  This implementation will let multiple threads enter the critical section, and step on each others initialization, potentially leading to disaster for a type with multiple members that are supposed to maintain some invariant.  Or with two pointers into the same buffer, you could get two allocations and one pointer to the start of one buffer, the other to the end of another.

Comment: Also totally unclear why you'd want a DI-mode type (twice the width of an `int`) for `__guard`, when you only use the low byte of it.  Spreading them out to avoid contention for cache lines between unrelated threads is a non-issue for single-threaded code, so just use `typedef char __guard`

Comment: (Since this doesn't have to be thread-safe, it's not a problem that we're using plain non-atomic load/store, rather than an atomic RMW.  The compiler itself probably still generates an acquire load for the inlined check of the guard variable, as in https://godbolt.org/z/6caWKcne8 (x86 does acquire for free, ARM64 can use ldarb instead of ldrb; other ISAs may need a barrier.)

Answer (score 3):

> ... leading me to believe the static variable as been initialized again.

This might be a right perception in terms you allow `Machine` and `Pc` instances to be publicly constructed (or copied).

Well, your code here

```
Pc* Pc::getInstance() {
    static Pc* pc = new Pc();
    return pc;
}
```

and the signature of the method

```
static Machine* getInstance();
```

should better be

```
Pc& Pc::getInstance() {
    static Pc theInstance;
    return theInstance;
}

static Machine& getInstance();
```

also make default, copy constructors, assignment operators for both classes `Machine` and `Pc` private.
Thus only reference variables can be actually used, to access the singleton instance

```
Machine& mach = Pc::getInstance();
Machine m2; // Fails to compile
```

**UPDATE:**
But I see a general problem here, that makes your whole design a bit questionable:

```
Machine& Machine::getInstance() {
    return Pc::getInstance();
}
```

This makes the `Machine` class dependent on it's derived class, which makes a base class pretty useless at all.

---

What about using a template class for solving this problem?

```
template<class Derived>
class Machine {
public:
     static Derived& getInstance() {
          static Derived theInstance;
          return theInstance;
     }
protected:
     Machine() {
         Derived* self = static_cast<Derived*>(this); // Ensure that Derived
                                                      // inherits from Machine
         (void)self; // suppress compiler warning for unused variable
     }
private:
     Machine(const Machine&);
     Machine& operator=(const Machine&);
};

class Pc : public Machine<Pc> {
    friend class Machine<Pc>;
    Pc() : Machine<Pc>() {}
};

int main() {
    Pc& pc = Pc::getInstance(); // Get a reference of the Pc singleton
    return 0;
}
```

See a [fully working sample here](http://ideone.com/ypmUev).

---

As for your mentions of the `-ffreestanding` compiler options:

First, it's a c compiler option (shouldn't affect your c++ code), second as I found in the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards)

> GCC aims towards being usable as a conforming freestanding implementation, or as the compiler for a conforming hosted implementation. By default, it will act as the compiler for a hosted implementation, defining **STDC_HOSTED** as 1 and presuming that when the names of ISO C functions are used, they have the semantics defined in the standard. To make it act as a conforming freestanding implementation for a freestanding environment, use the option -ffreestanding; it will then define **STDC_HOSTED** to 0 and not make assumptions about the meanings of function names from the standard library, with exceptions noted below. To build an OS kernel, you may well still need to make your own arrangements for linking and startup. See [Options Controlling C Dialect](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options).

This doesn't give me any points about a undefined behavior of local static initialization.

Comment: Machine implements methods for many different architectures (Pc/Mac etc) so the base class implements globally available functions, where as the derived classes implement further variable types, and the implementation of some virtual functions. 
Also this code still fails to work - the Pc constructor gets called multiple times as before, what are the requirements of using static locals? i am compiling with -ffreestanding does this remove support for them?

Comment: @Mattiemus _'Machine implements methods for many different architectures'_ This can still well be done using this pattern. _'and the implementation of some virtual functions.'_ You don't need virtual functions with my proposal at all (see the `static_cast<>` for `self`). I'd suppose you'll need one architecture at a time right? I can't actually find a documentation for that `-ffreestanding` compiler option (do you have one?), but I doubt it really should influence the behavior of the local static initialization. That's something that's just defined from the current c++ standard.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I use the CRTP pattern for singletons too. It has worked well so far. BTW, you missed the return statement in the function.

Comment: I have had more time today to test this code - however it still does not work, the Machine<Pc> constructor gets called again on the second call to getInstance(), however the pointer remains the same (break pointing the constructor shows that the private variables have all been initialised correctly). 
Im starting to believe i may have found a bug in G++...

Comment: @Mattiemus Well, I made a [fork of my sample](http://ideone.com/pRQspG), and it works as expected for me (constructor is only called once). Which version of GCC are you using? Also note my solution proposal doesn't use a pointer, but references.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ G++ & GCC are both version 4.5.2 - I am recompiling them now to the latest version in a hope that this is a compiler bug - I am using references again and my code still doesn't work (my debugger shows me the addresses so i can see the object is being constructed twice, but in place both times). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mattiemus GCC 4.5.2 is pretty old, especially regarding c++11 standards. The complete standard is available with GCC 4.9.